# Office Scripts - How can I convert .xlsb to .xlsx

Tags: office-scripts

How can I convert my xlsb file to a xlsx?
I seem unable to use `SaveAs` as getting an error `Property 'SaveAs' does not exist in workbook`

trying -

```
workbook.SaveAs(filepath.Replace(".xlsb",".xlsx"), XlFileFormat.xlExcel12, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, 
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

current code -

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, password: string) {
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Draft");

  selectedSheet.getProtection().unprotect("pass");

  // Toggle auto filter on selectedSheet
  selectedSheet.getAutoFilter().remove();

  // Delete range 1:6 on selectedSheet
  selectedSheet.getRange("1:6").delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);



}
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Comment: No, Office Scripts can’t create files. It can only work with them. Have you looked at other operations with LA/PA when it comes to copying and renaming files?